# Image on website is disappearing on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, google-web-designer

I've added an image to the home page of my website, and it all looks good on my big screen, however, when I go to view the website from a smaller laptop, it doesn't show the image. Any tips on how to make the website more responsive, so that this image appears on all devices? (or just on the web, not too bothered about mobile)

This is the code I've used to add the image:

```html
<h2 class="main-heading no-margin"/>
    <section class="home-welcome text-center padding show-for-medium" style="padding-left: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important; padding-top: 0!important;">
       <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyhxHP0/Screenshot-2022-05-10-at-12-04-57.jpg" style="width: 100%;"/>

    </section>
```

This is what I'd like the website to look like (and it does on my big mac screen):

[image]

This is what it currently looks like on a smaller screen:

[image]

Comment: did you add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your `<head>`?

Comment: Might be worth looking at what this css class is defined as `show-for-medium`

Comment: did you find a solution to this?